# Why changes to my Flask App on IIS are delayed (html content like text,forms,...)?

Tags: python, flask, iis

I have a Flask App on IIS and when I add text to my html pages or edit html pages that change applied delayed after 30 minutes or more.
But When I run the App locally after any refresh that applied.

I  disable cache in IIS like [this link](http://www.devinbaldwin.com/2010/09/30/disable-cache-in-iis/)  as shown as but It had no effect.

[image: disable cache in IIS]

My IIS version=10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fast way to refresh the latest program is to recycle the Application Pool.

```
IIS -> Application Pools -> Select the Application Pool -> Recycle
```

After recycling, your application cache will be cleared.
[Application Pools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY0UE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please go to IIS manager->site level->Http Response Headers->set common header->check whether expire web content has been enabled. In addition, please check whther any other cache control header is affecting this.

And after editing html pages, did you clear the browser cache? I think there is no way to manually refresh the IIS output caching immediately unless do an IISRESET or restart the APP.

Comment: I set as you say but not effect.

Comment: Have you tried other situations? For example, you only publish an html page, and then update its content to see if the content changes after refresh.